# How to view history of database updates

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, schema-compare

If I have a database project that's connected to an Azure Sql db v12, is there a way to see a history of the "Schema Updates" I've run on that database?  Similar to a Git history of commits?  I know there's something called a refactorlog and I looked around a little to see if that could be of some help but it doesn't appear to be.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't enable auditing or some custom solution to capture changes,you have no way to see historical changes..With that said,below are some of options you can try to capture schema changes in azure.

1.DDL triggers
2.SQL azure Auditing feature

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped me figure out what to do.  I'm going to mark your question as the accepted one because you provided more options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be able to get this. However you can add a DDL trigger to track these changes by keeping the changes in a different auditing table.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it led me in the right direction.